# Re loadable properties from database

Tags: spring

we are planning to move our properties to database trying to make it re-loadable.

we are injecting properties value in code using

```
@Value("${name}")
String name;


### our properties file is like
name=zuned
```

Just wondering Spring 3.1 provide some feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do so , have uploaded my POC on gitHub

https://github.com/zuned/dynamic_property_loading

Answer (score 0):

Have been thinking about this as well.
I found this article which seems good:
http://pure-essence.net/2011/02/10/spring-loading-properties-from-database-with-a-twist/

But have not tried it.
Don't think spring provides anything out of the box for this.